# c++ local vs member variable performance

Tags: c++, performance, local, member

The intention of the question is efficeincey a good reason to use local variable than member , I am not trying to test compiler optimization here ... Please

If you think my comparision isn't perfect , kindly provide an alternative code.

Any one can explain in detail why ?
Why Local acess is faster even if it has to crteate stack and dismantle stack everytime it calls the function 
While member it just has to derefrence this pointer 
I can see local stack is faster ?

---

RESULT
local time:271
member time:418

Code :

```
class local {
public:
 void incr() {
        int i;
        ++i;
}


};


class Member {
int i;

public:
 void incr() {
        ++i;
}

};

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv) {

        time_t star;
        time_t end;
        Member m;
        local l;
        time(&star);
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<200000;++j)
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<400000;++i) {
                l.incr();
        }
        time(&end);
        std::cout << "\nlocal time:" << end-star << "\n";

        time(&star);
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<200000;++j)
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<400000;++i) {
                m.incr();
        }
        time(&end);
        std::cout << "\nmember time:" << end-star<< "\n";
return 0;
}
```

NEW CODE:
g++  -O1 localmember.cpp

local time:128
member time:117

Code :

```
class local {
public:
 int diff(int a, int b) {
        int d=0;
        d=a-b;
        return d;
}
};


class Member {
int d;

public:
 int diff(int a, int b) {
        d=0;
        d=a-b;
        return d;
}

};

static int gr;
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
void dumpdiff(int r) {
gr=r ;
}
int main(int argc, char**argv) {

        time_t star;
        time_t end;
        Member m;
        local l;
        int r=0;
        int r2=0;
        time(&star);
        int in1=2,in2=0;
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<200000;++j)
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<200000;++i) {
                r = l.diff(in1*i,in2*i);
                in1+=1;
                in2+=1;
                if(r){r2=r;}
                dumpdiff(r);
        }
        time(&end);
        std::cout << "\nlocal time:" << end-star << "\n";

        time(&star);
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<200000;++j)
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<200000;++i) {
                r = m.diff(in1,in2);
                in1+=1;
                in2+=1;
                if(r){r2=r;}
                dumpdiff(r);
        }
        time(&end);
        std::cout << "\nmember time:" << end-star<< "\n";
return 0;
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/vKeLlL 0 and 0 here. Your benchmark is done wrong. You probably didn't use optimizations at all, which makes benchmarking utterly useless. You should also have different programs for the two situations, it's not unheard of that even switching loops between each other modifies resutls.

Comment: Another reason your benchmark is useless is that you're comparing apples to oranges. Even without optimizations, the two do different things. Completely different. So what's the point of the comparison?

Comment: You're classes/methods doesn't even have side-effects. I'm pretty sure this could be optimized to no-op by the compiler.

Comment: The intention of the question is is efficeincey a good reason to use local varianbles than member , I am not trying to test compoiler optimization here ... Please

Comment: Luchian's right - as usual ;-) - "benchmark is useless".  Also, `int i; ++i;` - incrementing an uninitialised variable has undefined behaviour.  More generally, your argument re performance isn't sound: "has to crteate stack and dismantle stack everytime it calls the function" applies to both (indeed, any non-inline function), and a single stack pointer adjustment when calling a function might well include space for local variables - after which accessing stack-pointer-relative data shouldn't be slower than object's `this`-pointer relative.  Look at optimised asm if you want to get a feel.

Comment: @tony well it would have been nice & good explanation about stack  if I leave rest opf unwanted comment

Comment: @toney also excplain how an has undefined behaviour  would have impacted benchmark ?

Comment: @AnandRathi: supporting Luchian's statement may be "unwanted", but it's important that future readers aren't misled by your question/conclusions. Supporting Luchian helps. Your other question: undefined behaviour may do anything - if you want a reliable benchmark you should do what you can to ensure the Standard requires it to be valid, not hope for the best because you haven't thought of a reason for it to matter. It's also good practice to do things that inhibit unintended optimisation, e.g. initialise to argc (compiler can't know it), add argc per loop iteration; print results.

Comment: personally it sounds like you people have grouped to discourage  people asking questions , I don't feel like asking questions with this attitude. At least provide an alternative code or correct the code 

I have appreciated the technical answer about access to stack , which explains why the difference in performance .. and thanks for extra goodies about BEST practices.

Comment: @AnandRathi: "benchmark is useless" is a simple statement of fact not personal criticism, and it has been followed by lots of advice as to why and what to do about it: enable optimisation, separate behaviours into two programs, initialise variables before use, inhibit unwanted optimisations by using values that can't be known at compile time such as `argc` and printing results, and inspect assembly.  Judging from your question I'd say you could implement all of these without needing more explicit code examples, but if you have a specific question feel free to ask.

Comment: @tony D , Thanks but no Thanks :
You have provided the correct answer about stack , That was the intention .. refer my question 
I dont agree about all other comments of yours including .. they are simply useless 
I am happy to modify the code so that variable is used so that unwanted optimization is avoided .. but again I had explicitly made clear what I intended to know about stack vs derefrencing this pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your compiler can see that you never read `i` in `local::incr`. If you don't read it, there is no need to increment it, so the compiler just can optimize anything away that has to do with `local`. And doing *nothing* of course is faster than doing anything.

However, I doubt that you compiled with full optimization, or else the compiler would have seen that the stuff related to `Member` doesn't do anything, too, and then you would have gotten 0 and 0 both times, because good optimizers can see enough to optimize even the loops away, because they don't have side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Whether a variable is local vs member is not as important to performance as cache locality and register displacement.

Given your remarks about "not testing optimization", I suspect that your "question" is "How can I test prove whether one is faster than the other?"

The answer is: You have to look at the assembly (e.g. gcc -o test.S -S test.cpp). With -O1 or higher, GCC completely eliminates the calls to your Local.incr() function, which obviously invalidates the test.

However: if you, presumably, compiled with -O0 then you were frontloading the test in favor of local variables because with -O0 the cost of member operations was raised - it's more expensive to call member functions that access member variables.

I took your example and changed it to this:

```
void incr() {
    int i;
    ++i;
}

class local {
public:
    void incr() {
        int i;
        ++i;
    }
};

class member {
    int m_i;
public:
    void incr() {
        ++m_i;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    local l;
    member m;

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 200000; ++j) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 400000; ++i) {
            incr();
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 200000; ++j) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 400000; ++i) {
            l.incr();
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 200000; ++j) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 400000; ++i) {
            m.incr();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -O0 -g -o test.S -S test.cpp", the implementation of "incr" is

```
_Z4incrv:
.LFB0:
    .file 1 "test.cpp"
    .loc 1 1 0
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
.LCFI1:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
.LBB2:
    .loc 1 3 0
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.LBE2:
    .loc 1 4 0
    popq    %rbp
.LCFI2:
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

While local::incr is

```
_ZN5local4incrEv:
.LFB1:
    .loc 1 8 0
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
.LCFI3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
.LBB3:
    .loc 1 10 0
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.LBE3:
    .loc 1 11 0
    popq    %rbp
.LCFI5:
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Because it has to receive the "this" pointer. But it didn't access any member variables, so it didn't actually have to use the this pointer in any way.

```
_ZN6member4incrEv:
.LFB2:
    .loc 1 17 0
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
.LCFI6:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI7:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    .loc 1 18 0
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %eax
    leal    1(%rax), %edx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, (%rax)
    .loc 1 19 0
    popq    %rbp
.LCFI8:
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

In this kind of debug build, with -O0, member access is always going to be more expensive. If I add an "m_j" to Member and also increment that in Member::incr(), the compiler goes ahead and generates:

```
    .loc 1 20 0
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    4(%rax), %eax
    leal    1(%rax), %edx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, 4(%rax)
```

So yes - in an unoptimized build, in most scenarios, for trivial cases, member variables are more expensive than local variables.

"most scenarios"? If the type is not a simple type, with an expensive constructor, etc, then you will have to run the constructor every time you enter the function, as opposed to having to run it once. Consider:

```
void simulated_work() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds<5000>; }

struct DatabaseInteger {
    int m_i;
public:
    DatabaseInteger() {
        simulated_work();
    }
    inline DatabaseInteger& operator++() { ++m_i; }
    operator int() { return m_i; }
};

class local {
public:
    void incr() {
        DatabaseInteger i; // does simulated_work every time.
        ++i;
    }
};
```

"local" variables are going to be more efficient than member variables any time, that is, if:

- there's no construction overhead,
- you aren't using them in a case where they result in register displacement,
- you aren't making the stack stupidly deep,
- you aren't forcing yourself to pass large numbers of additional arguments from/to functions,
- you aren't forcing yourself to use extra registers to capture lots of return values.

Comment: I have figured out with O3 optimization , and doing something useful after increment there isn't large speed difference 

local time:769
member time:767

With O1 
local time:128
member time:117

The member always fared better ..

Comment: To generate the assembly listing, use "g++ -Wall -O3 -g -o test.S -S test.cpp"

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball tells me that the compiler is optimizing away the local variable code, while it can't prove that the member variable isn't accessed later and that increment is actually done.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Tony D answers in my inbox 
"has to create stack and dismantle stack every time it calls the function" applies to both (indeed, any non-inline function), and a single stack pointer adjustment when calling a function might well include space for local variables - after which accessing stack-pointer-relative data shouldn't be slower than object's this-pointer relative. Look at optimised asm if you want to get a feel. – Tony D